# If A and B are independent events, such that $P(A\cap B')=1/3$ and $P(A'\cap B)= 1/6$. What is the value of P(A)?

Tags: probability

If A and B are independent events, such that $P(A\cap B')=1/3$ and $P(A'\cap B)= 1/6$. What is the value of P(A)?

I tried to solve but, I got P(A)=(1/6)+p(B). After this what should I do.

Anyone kindly help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If $A,B$ are independent, so are $A',B$ and $A,B'$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\frac 1 3 &= P(A) P(B') = P(A) (1 - P(B)) = P(A) - P(A)P(B) \\
 \frac 1 6 &= P(A') P(B) = (1-P(A)) P(B) = P(B) - P(A)P(B)
\end{align*}$$

The scenario might be a bit easier to parse by letting $\alpha = P(A)$ and $ \beta = P(B)$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\frac 1 3 &= \alpha - \alpha \beta  \\
 \frac 1 6 &= \beta - \alpha \beta
\end{align*}$$

Hence, $\alpha - \beta = 1/6$ as you have seen, by subtracting the pair of equations.

Then $\alpha = \beta + 1/6$, and using this in the first equation gives

$$\begin{align*}
\frac 1 3 &= \frac 1 6 + \beta - \left( \frac 1 6 + \beta \right) \beta =\frac 1 6 + \frac 5 6 \beta - \beta^2
\end{align*}$$

Solve for $\beta$, and then solve for $\alpha$.

Comment: Sir, I solved as per you said. I got now P(A)= 1/3 and P(B)=1/6. Is this correct sir?

Comment: Well, you can check it for yourself by plugging those back into the relations, no?

Comment: To see if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the solutions of the equation :
$$x^2 + a x + b = 0$$
verify that $\alpha + \beta = -a$ and $\alpha \beta = b$.

Comment: It looks obvious that $P(A)>\frac13$ and $P(B)>\frac16$